# Xcode UITest unable to test wechat login

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

It is a Chinese app that has third parties login which is similar to facebook login. I tried wechat login. The app jump to wechat app, I can see the confirm login button, but UITests stop at wechat screen.

here is log:

```
 t =    17.90s         Wait for app to idle
    t =    18.06s         Find the "denglu 0012 weixin login" Button
    t =    18.06s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.nadouxing.development
    t =    18.27s             Find: Descendants matching type Button
    t =    18.27s             Find: Elements matching predicate '"denglu 0012 weixin login" IN identifiers'
    t =    18.29s             Wait for app to idle
    t =    18.44s         Synthesize event
    t =    18.81s         Wait for app to idle
    t =    21.44s             App event loop idle notification not received, will attempt to continue.
    t =    21.44s             App animations complete notification not received, will attempt to continue.
    t =    23.46s     Tap "确认登录" Button
    t =    23.46s         Wait for app to idle
    t =    25.48s             Unable to monitor animations
    t =    31.61s             Unable to monitor event loop
    t =    31.75s             App event loop idle notification not received, will attempt to continue.
    t =    31.76s             App animations complete notification not received, will attempt to continue.
    t =    31.76s         Find the "确认登录" Button
    t =    31.76s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.nadouxing.development
    t =    37.87s                 Unable to monitor animations
    t =    44.02s                 Unable to monitor event loop
    t =    47.12s                 Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: UI Testing Failure - Failed to get snapshot within 15.0s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't interact with any app other than the one you are making, and you can only UI test one app at a time. (Even if you made the wechat app yourself, there is no option to interact with them both using XCTest.)

Your UI tests are tied to a single bundle ID, and they are not able to interact with any app other than the one with that bundle ID. Only information from the app with that bundle ID will be retrieved and you must have access to a debug version of that app.